# Launch new window in Mac app

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm writing my first mac application coming from an iOS background.

I'm a little confused as to how windows work in mac apps. In an iOS app, you create an instance of a class and pass it the initWithNibName message, then push it on the view stack.

How do you launch a new window in a mac application? Is it better to have all of your windows in one nib file, or to create a new NSWindowController for each window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar, the initWithNibName is the same but you then send the controller a showWindow: message, if you create a document based application you don't have to worry about this unless you create additional windows. It is usually much better and easier to have a separate nib and controller for each window type, the exception may be for something simple that acts like an alert.